# Errors when placing a site asp.net framework on iis

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

I created a simple website on asp.net a framework that has standard user authentication, that is, re-registration, but I added the fields I need to it and sent it to the sql server database, not to the local database, as it was before.

Now when you try to log in or register for some reason first of all such a request is made in the address bar :

/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FAccount%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FAccount%2525252FLogin%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FAccount%252525252FLogin%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FAccount%25252525252FLogin%25252525253FReturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252FAccount%2525252525252FLogin%2525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525253D%252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252FLogin%252525252525253FReturnUrl%25

And this is not the whole query, there is about 4000 characters repeating like this. and on the page in the Opera there is such an error:

> "ERR_TOO-MANY_REDIRECT"

If you refresh the page after a minute, you get this error:

> "BAD REQUEST - REQUEST TOO LONG. HTTP ERROR 400. THE SIZE OF REQUEST HEADER TOO LONG"

I found somewhere on the forum the answer, that need to fulfill the next

> For Internet information services (IIS) 6.0 and later, the MaxFieldLength and MaxRequestBytes registry keys are located in the following subkey:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters

I kind of asked this.
But it's still the same.
Here is the iis server log:

135 400 - RequestLength -
2020-01-23 04:20:40 ::1%0 12889 ::1%0 443 HTTP/2 GET

Tell me how to fix it? should be such as to allow long such a request? or is it a jamb in the code and the request should not be this size? but this is a standard Asp registration created automatically. Please help me fix the error

Comment: Is maybe your login page also protected, and only reachable by logged-in users? You should allow anonymous requests there. Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple)

Comment: Your login page is redirecting to itself with an error, which is then redirecting to the login page.... your request grows quite large after many such self redirects, and you blow the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Please post your code and IIS authentication configuration. It looks just like you have block anonymous access for all controller and also enabled form authentication for /Account/Login.  Anonymous authentication for /Account/Login didn't being enabled. So when your website try to access /Account/Login, your application will get into a loop to itself.

So the most important thing is enable anonymous access for /Account/Login.